# Retrieve most recent opened files

Tags: javascript, node.js

Is there a quick way on getting the list of most recent opened files through NodeJS? I was trying to do it by traversing the directories and sorting all files by access time.

Mac finder already have the `Recents` tab, and I was hoping there is a way to retrieve that list?

I'm pretty sure Windows has this list of recent files too.

Comment: You may need to implement something like this yourself - e.g. every time you do `fs.readFile(fp)`, you also append the `fp` string into some file. Then this separate file will list all recent file access actions.

Comment: @Gershom, right this is what I will do as backup solution if there is no way to retrieve the recent file list. I'll be going through the directories recursively, then check the `atime` of files